# Invalid command line option: --set-version

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get WSL 2 running. To wit I did the following:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName VirtualMachinePlatform
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

The next step, according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install, is to make a distro use WSL2 vs WSL1. To do that you need to do `wsl --set-version <Distro> 2`. I tried that, substituting `<Distro>` for `Ubuntu` and got the following error:

```
Invalid command line option: --set-version
```

So I guess I don't have WSL2 installed idk.

I'm running Windows 10 Build 18362.356.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm running Windows 10 Build 18362.356.

You need to be on build 18917 or greater, and already have WSL 1 installed

See

[Invalid command line options #419](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/419)

and

[WSL 2 install documentation updated to include links to instructions on how to install WSL 1.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install)